# how can to fill row of DataGrid from behindcode in wpf

Tags: wpf

When I click on button1 the datagrid loaded but why my texts(text1 & name1) are not shown in cells of datagrid?

its design code:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" Name="dataGrid" Width="200">
                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" />
                                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="visible" />
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" />
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
```

its behindcode:

```
  public class DataGridStructure
    {
        public bool visible { get; set; }
        public string NameField { get; set; }
        public string HeaderText { get; set; }

    }
    public List<DataGridStructure> CreateDataTable()
    {

        List<DataGridStructure> dgs = new List<DataGridStructure>();
         dgs.Add(new DataGridStructure() {HeaderText="text1", NameField="name1", visible=true});
       return dgs;  

     }
```

its behind code of my button1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = CreateDataTable();
    }
```

tell me if the more information needed, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XAML code has no bindings to the properties you want to display. With the AutoGenerateColumns="False" this is a must.
At the very least your class needs to implement the  INotifyPropertyChanged interface for the properties you want to be displayed in the DataGrid.
You also should not be using List to bind to the ItemsSource, but have the [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

You XAML should look something like that:

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}" Height="200" Name="dataGrid" Width="200">
                                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Visible" Binding="{Binding visible}" />
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" Binding="{Binding Header}" />
                                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                                </DataGrid>
```

And the code behind:

```
    public class DataGridStructure : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private bool _visible = false;
    public bool visible { 
        get{ return _visible; }
        set{ 
            _visible = value;
            set{ OnPropertyChanged("visible");
        }
    }

    private string _nameField = string.Empty;
    public bool NameField { 
        get{ return _nameField; }
        set{ 
            _nameField = value;
            set{ OnPropertyChanged("NameField");
        }
    }

    private string _headerText = string.Empty;
    public bool HeaderText { 
        get{ return _headerText; }
        set{ 
            _headerText = value;
            set{ OnPropertyChanged("HeaderText");
        }
    }        
}

public void CreateDataTable()
{
     MyItemsSource.Add(new DataGridStructure() {HeaderText="text1", NameField="name1", visible=true});       
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = this;
}

 private ObservableCollection<DataGridStructure> _dataGridStructure = new ObservableCollection<DataGridStructure>();
 public ObservableCollection<DataGridStructure> MyItemsSource{get{ return _dataGridStructure; }}
```

Comment: You should set bindings to "Binding" properties not "Header". Header is simply column header text and not a data value.

Comment: I did not test the code, but yes I agree it had to be a Binding property to display the data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to enable autogeneratecolumns or set Bindings for each column you manually define.